# How to encode custom attribute filed input value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

I have added column password_custom in table eav_attribute customer. I want to encode the input data. How do I do that? I followed the instructions here
https://vacademyideas.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-field-in-magento-2-registration-form/

result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Rmz.png
desired result

admin@123 ==> LAdsuiwqebwquihdsa121iydsai

Input data must be encrypted.

Comment: use "customer_register_success" observer to manipulate the value and set it to the respective user/customer - refer this link for more detail https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240163/77554

Answer (score 0):

To convert the password, you can use this code.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;

public function __construct(EncryptorInterface $encryptor) 
{
    $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
}

public function encryptPassword($your_password)
{
    return $this->encryptor->encrypt($your_password);
}

public function decryptPassword($your_password)
{
    return $this->encryptor->decrypt($your_password);
}
```

Comment: where is it used in observer or plugin?  i know this function is in Magento but when i save password in attribute where are they encrypted or is it in InstallData.php

Comment: You can use this in place where you want to save the data into that field.